# Unit Testing Android project gets a NoClassDefFoundError for 3rd Party Jars

Tags: android

I'm trying to run unit tests on my Android app and I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError when referencing 3rd party jars.

The classes in those jars are only referenced by the app itself, not the unit tests. The jars are on the apps classpath and have been exported in the eclipse settings to allow tyhem to be found by dependant apps - which, of course, the test app is.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. Please don't simply tell me that my jars aren't on the classpath - I can see that, I'm just not seeing how to get them on the classpath...

Comment: Does the application itself successfully utilize the jars?  Do they contain davlik bytecode and not just java bytecode (which will not work)?

Comment: Ah - they are just standard Java jars - I guess that's the problem. How should I recompile them (assuming that's what I need to do) in order for them to work with the Dalvik VM?

Comment: The more I look around, the more I wonder if eclipse shouldn't be doing this for me as part of creating the apk...

Comment: If it helps - the jars are the Google gdata ones and their dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - it looks like I can use the google-api jars and they should work.